# Javascript can't add an argument to a function with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

i have a code that should do heatmap when applied to html table:

**html table code:**

```
<table class='table' id='js-datatable' cellspacing="0.9" cellpadding="8" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>product</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Jan</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Feb</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Mar</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Apr</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>May</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>K22</td>
        <td align=center>655$</td>
        <td align=center>365$</td>
        <td align=center>265$</td>
        <td align=center>125$</td>
        <td align=center>36$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>K52</td>
        <td align=center>90</td>
        <td align=center>50</td>
        <td align=center>120</td>
        <td align=center>80</td>
        <td align=center>190</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>J42</td>
        <td align=center>1267</td>
        <td align=center>1567</td>
        <td align=center>347</td>
        <td align=center>697</td>
        <td align=center>70</td>
    </tr>
    <script src='https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</table>
```

**javаscript file code:**

```
function clean_formatted_data(str) {
    return parseFloat (str.replace (/([%,$,\,])+/g, ''));
}

function col_to_array(tbl_col, target) {
    // Returns column `n` (zero indexed) in table id `target` as an array

    var colArray = $ ('#' + target + ' td:nth-child(' + tbl_col + ')').map (function () {
        return clean_formatted_data ($ (this).text ());
    }).get ();

    return colArray;
}

//------ new schtuff ------------------------//

function get_pos_of_max(col_data) {
    return $.inArray (Math.max.apply (Math, col_data), col_data)
}

function generate_opacities(col_data, max) {
    var opacity_array = [];
    var increment = max / (col_data.length);

    for (i = col_data.length; i >= 1; i--) {
        opacity_array.push (i * increment / 100);
    }

    return opacity_array;
}


function process_col_best_performing(tbl_col, target) {
    var col_data = col_to_array (tbl_col, target);
    var opacity_array = generate_opacities (col_data, 50);
    var row_count = col_data.length;

    for (var i = 1; i <= row_count; i++) {
        $ ('#' + target + ' tr:nth-child(' + (get_pos_of_max (col_data) + 1) + ') td:nth-child(' + tbl_col + ')').css ('background', 'rgba(0,0,255,' + opacity_array[0] + ')');
        col_data[get_pos_of_max (col_data)] = null;
        for (const spliceElement of opacity_array.splice (0, 1)) {

        }

    }
}
```

lets say i have 5 columns, so my javascript function can be applied in this way:

```
process_col_best_performing (tbl_col:1, target:'js-datatable');
process_col_best_performing (tbl_col:2, target:'js-datatable');
process_col_best_performing (tbl_col:3, target:'js-datatable');
```

But because this is only an example, real html table can have any amount of columns i want to make this with a for loop, i tried with code below, but its not working

```
var cols_qty = document.getElementById ('js-datatable').rows[0].cells.length
var i;
for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    process_col_best_performing(tbl_col=i,'js-datatable');
}
```

*I'm totally new in javascript, so if you know the answer, please explain it in the simplest way as possible.

Comment: Not sure this will help, try changing your `process_col_best_performin` function calls to `process_col_best_performing (1, 'js-datatable');`. You only want to pass the value data through `js` function params, do not declare the param name and the value, just set the desired passed value in function parameters.

Comment: Nope, this don't work either

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can easily run it and see what's wrong. If you added in the table you're using you could create a runnable code example. Other than what @joshmoto said (which, if it solved your problem or not, was definitely another problem you would have run into), this would have to be reproduced in another environment but we don't have all the context.

Comment: I added htmltable code in the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but try the below code, the first thing do not declare as global var i; before the for loop, I am not sure if you are doing the same in your code, but the same i is getting changed inside the function and affecting the loop where you are calling process_col_best_performing. Check the below code and see if this make sense.

```js
var cols_qty = document.getElementById ('js-datatable').rows[0].cells.length
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    process_col_best_performing(i,'js-datatable');
}

function clean_formatted_data(str) {
    return parseFloat (str.replace (/([%,$,\,])+/g, ''));
}

function col_to_array(tbl_col, target) {
    // Returns column `n` (zero indexed) in table id `target` as an array

    var colArray = $ ('#' + target + ' td:nth-child(' + tbl_col + ')').map (function () {
        return clean_formatted_data ($ (this).text ());
    }).get ();

    return colArray;
}

//------ new schtuff ------------------------//

function get_pos_of_max(col_data) {
    return $.inArray (Math.max.apply (Math, col_data), col_data)
}

function generate_opacities(col_data, max) {
    var opacity_array = [];
    var increment = max / (col_data.length);

    for (var i = col_data.length; i >= 1; i--) {
        opacity_array.push (i * increment / 100);
    }

    return opacity_array;
}


function process_col_best_performing(tbl_col, target) {
    var col_data = col_to_array (tbl_col, target);
    var opacity_array = generate_opacities (col_data, 50);
    var row_count = col_data.length;

    for (var i = 1; i <= row_count; i++) {
        $ ('#' + target + ' tr:nth-child(' + (get_pos_of_max (col_data) + 1) + ') td:nth-child(' + tbl_col + ')').css ('background', 'rgba(0,0,255,' + opacity_array[0] + ')');
        col_data[get_pos_of_max (col_data)] = null;
        for (const spliceElement of opacity_array.splice (0, 1)) {

        }

    }
}
```

```html
 <script src='https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js'></script>
<table class='table' id='js-datatable' cellspacing="0.9" cellpadding="8" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>product</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Jan</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Feb</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Mar</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>Apr</th>
        <th align=center style="white-space: nowrap;" bgcolor=grey>May</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>K22</td>
        <td align=center>655$</td>
        <td align=center>365$</td>
        <td align=center>265$</td>
        <td align=center>125$</td>
        <td align=center>36$</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>K52</td>
        <td align=center>90</td>
        <td align=center>50</td>
        <td align=center>120</td>
        <td align=center>80</td>
        <td align=center>190</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='heatmap-stable'>
        <td align=center>J42</td>
        <td align=center>1267</td>
        <td align=center>1567</td>
        <td align=center>347</td>
        <td align=center>697</td>
        <td align=center>70</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```